# bash, remove files with letters in the filename

Tags: bash, alphanumeric, rm

I have a directory fill of files like the following:

```
1000.csv
1001.csv
aaa.csv
aac.csv
```

I want to remove the files like aaa.csv and aac.csv (basically anything that has [letters].csv, but keep the files that have [numbers].csv

Is there a way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you ask but with the caveat that this is a very dangerous command so make sure you designate the right path!

```
find ./ -type f -name '*[a-z]*.csv' | xargs rm
```

"./" is where you should put the path to the directory of the files you want to remove. This will also remove any file that contains letters. Even 12h.csv.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | grep [[:alpha:]*].csv | xargs rm
```

Should do what you want.

Edit:
ls will list the files in the directory, then pass that list to grep.
grep will take that list, and then filter out only the ones that begin with letters and then end in .csv, and will pass this new list to xargs.
xargs will take the list of files and pass it as an argument to rm.
rm will remove the files whose names it is passed.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, I get when I run this command: "rm: missing operand"

Comment: It works for me... What do you get when you run it without rm at the end? If that's blank, then grep isn't turning up any results, which would be the most likely problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, grep isn't turning up results which makes no sense. f.csv for example, is one of the files in that directory.

Comment: You could try using egrep and seeing if that does any better, or try playing around with the regex to see what comes up with broader things. Maybe try grepping for just a single filename, or try to get grep to return the list of all of them, just to see what part is going wrong.

Comment: +1 cause you had answered earlier and your solution works @qaphla :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
rm *[a-z]*.csv
```